# Laravel FirstorNew()/FirstorCreate() Error in relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have 2 table called product and color
products belongsTomany Colors and Colors belongsToMany Product using many to many relationship
now i am trying to add more color in single product and checking color name first if its not there than create new here is my code

```
public function addproductdetailspost(Request $request, $product){
    $color_name = $request->color;
    $product = product::where('slug', $product)->firstorfail();
    $color = color::where('name', $color_name)->firstOrNew();
    $color->name = $color_name;
    $color->save();
    $product_id = $product->id;
    dd($product_id);
    $color_id = $color->id;
    $color->products()->attach($product_id);
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Post Success');
}
```

but now i am getting error this

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::firstOrNew()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the `where` method for the Color model since `firstOrNew` does is it for you.

```
$color = color::firstOrNew(['name', $color_name]);
//$color->name = $color_name; No need s
$color->save();
```

[Laravel 5.4 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to add arguments

```
$color = color::where('name', $color_name)->firstOrCreate(['name' => $color_name]);
```

now its working